# How does this closure work? Is f born only after initializing g?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to understand why I need to call g() first before f(). Is it something about the execution context?

```js
let f;

const g = function () {
  const a = 23;
  f = function () {
    console.log(a * 2);
  };
};

g();
f();
```

I tried to switch f() and g() around but I could only use f() after calling g().

Comment: This isn't about the closure (except that it's how `f` accesses `a`) - `f` is undefined until after `g` has assigned a function to it.

Comment: A function has to be called to do anything. In this case, calling `g()` is the thing that assigns a function to `f`. Without calling `g()` there would be no assignment to `f`. There is no significance to `f` being assigned a function here, the code would work the same if it had `f = 42` inside `g()`.

Comment: It will be simple to understand if you used a string or number variable instead of function and tried to print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ignore the function for now. Consider the following:

```
let f = 2;

function g () {
    f = 100;
}

console.log(f);
```

Would you expect the value of `f` to be `100` or `2`?

Now what happens if you do this?

```
g();

console.log(f);
```

Is the value of `f` now `100`? Why?

The answer is obvious. When you call `g()` you assign the value `100` to `f`.

This is all that is happening. It is explained completely by how the `=` operator works. Nothing more, nothing less.